# Pythonic way to make row as column index and column as row index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I want to mutate the dataframe object. I want to make 1st row as column index. And 1st column as row index.

```
import pandas as pd

wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_state_and_union_territory_capitals_in_India"
df = pd.read_html(wiki)[1]
df2 = df.copy()
df2.head()
```

[image]

Currently I'm doing it like this (I'm loosing the row index name in this):

```
df2.columns = df.iloc[0]
df2.drop(0, inplace=True)
df2.drop('No.', axis=1, inplace=True)
df2.head()
```

[image]

How can I do it in a more Pythonic way preserving the row index name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify directly in the `read_html` your wishes, with `header` specifying which row to use as column, and `index_col` which column to use as index:

```
In [16]: df = pd.read_html(wiki,header=0,index_col=0)[1]

In [17]: df.head()
Out[17]: 
        State or union territory Administrative capitals Legislative capitals  \
No.                                                                             
1    Andaman and Nicobar Islands              Port Blair           Port Blair   
2                 Andhra Pradesh            Hyderabad[a]            Hyderabad   
3              Arunachal Pradesh                Itanagar             Itanagar   
4                          Assam                  Dispur             Guwahati   
5                          Bihar                   Patna                Patna   

    Judiciary capitals Year capital was established       The Former capital  
No.                                                                           
1              Kolkata                         1955     Calcutta (1945–1956)  
2            Hyderabad                         1959      Kurnool (1953-1956)  
3             Guwahati                         1986                      NaN  
4             Guwahati                         1975  Shillong[b] (1874–1972)  
5                Patna                         1912                      NaN
```

Comment: Any idea why df is returned in a list when doing pd.read_table?